# Stop editing this list throws javascript error

Tags: datasheet, quick-edit

I've got the following issue in SP'13 that I'm struggle to fix. When I have a list with no items in it and I use quick edit mode, but didn't add any rows and then click Stop editing this list it is throwing the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null

It happens because I have set the view to count the items in it and since there are no items in it 'aggrWPQ2' doesn't exist on the page. Do you have some easy fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to fixed this after all using JQuery that checks if 'aggrWPQ2' exists on the page and if not then adds it on prerendering.